# Destructuring nested object es6

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

how are you doing? I'd like to remove a property("isCorrect") from a nested object.

**Original List**

```
    id: 1,
    questionText: 'This is a test question for tests',
    answerOptions: [
      {
        answerText: 'A',
        isCorrect: true
      },
      {
        answerText: 'B',
        isCorrect: false
      }
    ],
    difficulty: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    questionText: 'This is another test question for tests',
    answerOptions: [
      {
        answerText: 'A',
        isCorrect: false
      },
      {
        answerText: 'B',
        isCorrect: true
      }
    ],
    difficulty: 2
  }
```

**Expected result**

```
    id: 1,
    questionText: 'This is a test question for tests',
    answerOptions: [
      {
        answerText: 'A'
      },
      {
        answerText: 'B'
      }
    ],
    difficulty: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    questionText: 'This is another test question for tests',
    answerOptions: [
      {
        answerText: 'A'
      },
      {
        answerText: 'B'
      }
    ],
    difficulty: 2
  }
```

I managed using delete code below but that is not that best approach

```
const cleanResponses = (questions: Question[]): Question[] => {
  questions.forEach(question => {
    question.answerOptions.forEach((answer) => {
      delete answer.isCorrect
    });
  })

  return questions;
}
```

Tried the line below but no success :(

*const { answerOptions: [{ isCorrect }], ...rest } = question*

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think `delete` is not best approach?

Comment: Is it because you don’t want to mutate the original copy, perhaps you still need to use it for other purpose?

Comment: Because I will mutate the object and that is not the plan. Good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1,
    questionText: 'This is a test question for tests',
    answerOptions: [ { answerText: 'A', isCorrect: true }, { answerText: 'B', isCorrect: false } ],
    difficulty: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    questionText: 'This is another test question for tests',
    answerOptions: [ { answerText: 'A', isCorrect: false }, { answerText: 'B', isCorrect: true } ],
    difficulty: 2
  }
];

const res = arr.map(({ answerOptions = [], ...elem }) => ({
  ...elem, 
  answerOptions: answerOptions.map(({ isCorrect, ...answer }) => answer)
}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, have a good one!!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to mutate the existing array, or create a new array. If it's the former your code is fine (I've provided an updated version below). If it's the latter Majed Badawi has provided a good answer using `map`. Either way you're going to be iterating over both the objects in the data array *and* the objects in the `answerOptions` array to get the result you need.

```js
const arr=[{id:1,questionText:"This is a test question for tests",answerOptions:[{answerText:"A",isCorrect:!0},{answerText:"B",isCorrect:!1}],difficulty:1},{id:2,questionText:"This is another test question for tests",answerOptions:[{answerText:"A",isCorrect:!1},{answerText:"B",isCorrect:!0}],difficulty:2}];

for (let { answerOptions } of arr) {
  for (let obj of answerOptions) {
    delete obj.isCorrect;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: thanks for the cleanup but the point I don't want to change the main obj! Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another (longer) way to achieve the desired output. Working from out to in, first we map across all objects in the array `test`. I use the rest operator to separate the array of `answerOptions` objects from the other question properties. Next, we need to map across the `answerOptions` array. Using the rest operator, create a new answerOption object that does not contain the `isCorrect` property. Finally, we bring it all back together. Return a object that contains the separated question properties and the new `answerOptions` objects without `isCorrect`.

```js
  const test = [
    {
      id: 1,
      questionText: "This is a test question for tests",
      answerOptions: [
        {
          answerText: "A",
          isCorrect: true
        },
        {
          answerText: "B",
          isCorrect: false
        }
      ],
      difficulty: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      questionText: "This is another test question for tests",
      answerOptions: [
        {
          answerText: "A",
          isCorrect: false
        },
        {
          answerText: "B",
          isCorrect: true
        }
      ],
      difficulty: 2
    }
  ];

  const cleanResponses = (questions) => {
    return questions.map(({ answerOptions, ...rest }) => {
      const newAnswerOptions = answerOptions.map((answerOption) => {
        const { isCorrect, ...newAnswerOption } = answerOption;
        return newAnswerOption;
      });
      return { answerOptions: { ...newAnswerOptions }, ...rest };
    });
  };
  
  console.log(cleanResponses(test))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it